# Android Gradle Project

Tags: android, gradle

I got the following error while run the gradle build.I think i missed some where in build.gradle,

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':checkFreeDebugManifest'.

> File 'E:\MyWorkspace\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for prope
>   rty 'manifest' does not exist.
>   
>   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create an AndroidManifest.xml file in your "main" folder. It is missing.
An example can be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.something" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- Define your activities and other stuffs here. -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```